# Penetration/Reflection properties of metals exposed to EM waves

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, reflection

I've read many questions being answered about how electromagnetic waves (being visible or not) can be reflected and/or absorbed and/or passed through objects.
I know some waves penetrate through paper, others penetrate glass and thin metal sheets, and some even pass through thick metals.

The question I have is, just as any element has specific physical and chemical properties, why for any element in the the periodic table, there isn't a specific property describing its behavior in exposure to EM waves?
(Just as refrective index coefficients, melting/boiling points, density, conductivity, megnetic susseptibility ,etc. for many media are well studied and measured and listed)

Isn't it a key property unique to each element/chemical to help with identification (or at least to measure purity)?

I'm sure I'm not remotely the first one with this idea (to measure reflection/absorbtion behavior of materials exposed to specific EM wavelengths)
But what exactly am I looking for?
Is there a list or a table presenting values describing such quality in some materials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Penetration in and reflection from materials are related to their the [complex refractive index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index#Complex_refractive_index). [RefractiveIndex.INFO](https://refractiveindex.info) lists wavelength-dependent refractive indices for many materials.

In general, the [permittivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permittivity) $\epsilon$ of a material is frequency-dependent and complex-valued (this also applies to permeability, I'll assume $\mu\approx\mu_0$ which is typically the case). Just like in materials with real permittivity, the complex refractive index can be defined as
$$\bar n = n-i\kappa= \sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon_0}}.$$
If $\epsilon$ is complex, so is $\bar n$. The real part $n$ is often just called the refractive index. The imaginary part $\kappa$ is called the extinction coefficient and describes how waves get attenuated (absorbed) by  the medium. The penetration depth is calculated as
$$\delta = \frac{\lambda}{4\pi\kappa}$$
where $\lambda$ is the wavelength in vacuum. A related quantity that is more frequently reported is the absorption coefficient $\alpha=1/\delta$. The lower the extinction coefficient, the farther the waves can penetrate into a material. For example, due to the high extinction coefficient of most metals in the visible spectrum (tied to their high conductivity), a thin sheet of metal is often still thicker than $\delta$, and hence opaque.

There is another factor that determines how transparent objects are, also related to $\bar n$. The [reflectance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflectance) (ratio of power reflected to power incident) for a wave normally incident (from vacuum) onto a material with a smooth surface and refractive index $\bar n$ is, by the [Fresnel equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations),
$$ R_\text{normal} = \left|\frac{\bar n - 1}{\bar n + 1}\right|^2 = \frac{(n-1)^2+\kappa^2}{(n+1)^2+\kappa^2}.$$
The more different $n$ is from $1$, or the higher the $\kappa$, the more reflective the surface. For example, due to the high $\kappa$ (and often $n<1$) of most metals, they reflect much of the incident wave, and this is another reason metal films tend to be opaque. Finally, surface roughness also plays a role here: objects with a rough (matte) surface can be more opaque.

Comment: Sorry to ask separately, does the proprties you mentioned (which I'll study on tomorrow) answer the question I asked in the comment of the other answer given? (The Ca and NaCl example)

Comment: Yes, in the sense that absorption coefficient and reflectance are calculated from the complex refractive index (RefractiveIndex.INFO even does this for you).  The above language is common in optical frequencies, X-rays interact with matter differently due to their short wavelengths (e.g. via diffraction/scattering, and $n\approx 1$ I believe). Consequently the terminology might be different for X-rays, e.g. [attenuation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attenuation_coefficient) instead of absorption coefficient.

Answer (score 0):

As you guessed correctly, for absorption, it is a key property of the elements, and it's called the emission spectrum, which could be used to measure the element compositions of a star. For example, [here](https://www.astronomy.ohio-state.edu/pogge.1/TeachRes/HandSpec/atoms.html).

There are tables describing these spectrum in more details, for example [here](https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/Handbook/Tables/ytterbiumtable2.htm) for Ytterbium.

Note: If an atom emits a light of specific frequency, it absorbs light of that frequency as well, so there's no need to differentiate between absorption and emission.

As for reflection, it's explained [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/35018/reflection-of-electromagnetic-waves?rq=1). Transmission is determined by the portion of light that doesn't interact with the material when passing through it.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me to read and learn some. But maybe I've asked the question the wrong way, or maybe the andwer is the same you gave. But what I mean is: let's assume we radiate two different chemicals (one being say Ca, the other NaCl) with X-ray, is there a table with values of how much is reflected by each so we know which is what by looking at the reflected rays and looking into that table?